# Javascript array data filter to array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array like:

```
ArrOfTime = ["Monday", "10:00-17:00", "Tuesday", "10:00-17:00", "17:00-21:00", "21:00-9:00", "Wednesday", "10:00-17:00", "17:00-21:00"]
```

I expect to change format to Array of objects like:

```
ArrOfObj = [
  {"day": "Monday", "time": "10:00-17:00"},
  {"day": "Tuesday", "time": "10:00-17:00, 17:00-21:00, 21:00-9:00"},
  {"day": "Wednesday", "time": "10:00-17:00, 17:00-21:00},
]
```

but I try some methods to change it formet which fail....

```
for (let i = 0; i < ArrOfTime.length; i += 2) {
  ArrOfObj.push({
    day: ArrOfTime[i],
    time: ArrOfTime[i + 1],
  });
}
```

How do I write my code will succeed to change the format like **ArrOfObj** ?

Comment: How does it exactly fail?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the following commented code. Please keep in mind that it assumes all 'day' strings will start with a letter and all 'time' strings will start with a number.

```js
const ArrOfTime = [
    'Monday',
    '10:00-17:00',
    'Tuesday',
    '10:00-17:00',
    '17:00-21:00',
    '21:00-9:00',
    'Wednesday',
    '10:00-17:00',
    '17:00-21:00'
];

function rearrange(input) {
    // CREATE OUTPUT ARRAY.
    const output = [];

    // OUTER VARIABLE TO STORE CURRENT OBJECT.
    let obj = null;

    // LOOP THROUGH INPUT ARRAY.
    input.forEach((item) => {
        // TEST IF item IS A DAY OR A TIME (USING FIRST CHARACTER).
        if (isNaN(parseInt(item[0]))) {
            // IF DAY, CREATE A NEW OBJECT AND STORE IT IN THE OUTER VARIABLE.

            if (obj) {
                // JOIN TIME ARRAY INTO A COMMA SEPARATED STRING.
                obj.time = obj.time.join(', ');
                // PUSH PREVIOUS OBJECT TO OUTPUT.
                output.push(obj);
            }

            obj = {
                day: item,
                time: []
            };
        } else {
            // IF TIME, PUSH TO TIME ARRAY.
            obj.time.push(item);
        }
    });

    // JOIN TIME ARRAY INTO A COMMA SEPARATED STRING.
    obj.time = obj.time.join(', ');
    // PUSH LAST OBJECT TO OUTPUT.
    output.push(obj);

    return output;
}

const ArrOfObj = rearrange(ArrOfTime);

console.log(ArrOfObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest solution I could come up with that works with every situation.

```js
let arrOfTime = ["Monday", "10:00-17:00", "Tuesday", "10:00-17:00", "17:00-21:00", "21:00-9:00", "Wednesday", "10:00-17:00", "17:00-21:00"]
let output = []
let daysIndices = []
let regex = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/

arrOfTime.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (regex.test(item)) daysIndices.push(index)
})

daysIndices.forEach((item, index) => {
    output.push({
        day: arrOfTime[item],
        time: arrOfTime.slice(item + 1, daysIndices[index + 1]).join(', ')
    })
})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize an array that contains day of weeks, then in `forEach` you could use `includes` to verify if element is a day of week; for `time` just concat with coma the other elements:

```js
let ArrOfTime = ["Monday", "10:00-17:00", "Tuesday", "10:00-17:00", "17:00-21:00", "21:00-9:00", "Wednesday", "10:00-17:00", "17:00-21:00"]

let dayOfWeek = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

let result = [];
let objRes = {};

ArrOfTime.forEach(x => {
   if(dayOfWeek.includes(x)) {
      if (objRes["day"]) objRes = {};
      objRes["day"] = x;
      result.push(objRes)
   }
   else objRes["time"] ? objRes["time"] = objRes["time"] + ', ' + x : objRes["time"] = x;
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
ArrOfTime = ["Monday", "10:00-17:01", "Tuesday", "10:00-17:02", "17:00-21:03", "21:00-9:04", "Wednesday", "10:00-17:05", "17:00-21:06"]

const hasNumber = /\d/;

let newArr = []

let obj = {}

for (let i = 0; i < ArrOfTime.length; i++){
 if( !hasNumber.test(ArrOfTime[i]) ){
     obj.time = '';
     obj.day = ArrOfTime[i];
    newArr.push(obj)
    obj = {}
 }  else if ( newArr[newArr.length-1].time === '') { 
     newArr[newArr.length-1].time = ArrOfTime[i]
    } else { 
        newArr[newArr.length-1].time = newArr[newArr.length-1].time + `, ${ArrOfTime[i]}`
         }  
}

console.log('newArr', newArr)
```